# Is there a way to set default lifetimemanager for container in unity

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I've seen a lot of articles that could use next syntax of configuring `UnityContainer`:

```
container.RegisterType(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Right now it doesn't work and i have to register my types like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IAlwaysTheSame, AlwaysTheSame>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IAlwaysTheSame, AlwaysTheSame>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ISameInARequest, SameInARequest>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IAlwaysDifferent, AlwaysDifferent>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

**Question:** is there a way to set default lifetimemanager for container (init or config)?

Comment: A workaround could be to create an extension method. But the downside is that `RegisterType` has a lot of overloads that you also would need to extend. Otherwise, check this link http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/352179